# dlsym in a different file and dlopen in a different file

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dlopen, dlsym

I have a shared libary which I dlopen(tried both RTLD_LAZY and RTLD_NOW) during my initialization routine. The handle returned from this is stored into a global void pointer (this is defined as extern in a header file abc.h)

Another API in the same library as my initialization routine uses the handle to lookup a symbol and call the API. But from what I see the pointer returned as part of this second API from dlsym is different from the one I check during my initialization API. It looks something like below.

## File init.c

```
include <stdio.h>
include <dlfcn.h>
include "init.h"
void *global_handle=NULL;

int init_api()
{
    global_handle = dlopen('xyz.so.1.0.1',RTLD_LAZY);
    printf("[DEBUG]: global handle from my init %p", global_handle);
    printf("[DEBUG]: dlsym xyz from my init from global handle=%p",
              dlsym(global_handle, 'abc'));
    return 0;
}
```

## File init.h

```
extern void *global_handle;
```

## File myfile.c

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include init.h

int my_api()
{
    int (*api)(int*);
    int a = 5;
    *(void**)(&api) = dlsym(global_handle,'abc');
    printf("[DEBUG]: global handle in my api=%p", global_handle);
    printf("[DEBUG]: dlsym xyz from my api using global handle=%p", 
                        api);
    int rc = (*api)(&a); /* >>>>> segfault on this call */
    printf("RC : %d", rc);
    return rc;
}
```

xyz.so contains symbol abc. I validated this using

```
strings xyz.so | grep abc
```

Any clue as to what might be causing this issue would be very helpful?

```
[DEBUG]: global handle from my init **0x55f6a5c8ae70**
[DEBUG]: dlsym xyz from my init from global handle=0x7fce**952ce010**
```

From another function

```
[DEBUG]: global handle in my api=**0x55f6a5c8ae70**
[DEBUG]: dlsym xyz from my api using global handle=0xffffffff**952ce010**
```

The handle is correct but the pointer for the symbol returned is not the same (there is a part of it ...maybe offset which is the same)

Comment: It's unlikely that we can guess the nature of the problem without code that reproduces it, *i.e.* a [mcve].

Comment: That looks to me like your printf format is not appropriate for the argument type. Or you've failed to declare `dlsym` and the return type is defaulting to `int`. Or some other type conversion problem which would be revealed if you compiled with `-Wall` and read through the warning messages.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have tried to add what I tried to describe as code. Could you cehck and let me know if this helps?

Comment: There are a lot of typos in the code you pasted which will prevent it from being compiled without errors, so I guess that it is not your real code. It would be useful if you could fix those errors and verify that you see the same problem; see the SO help on creating a [mcve]. However, what I do see is that your api function is declared as taking a pointer argument, but you're calling it with a simple integer. If it really expects a pointer, that would definitely cause a segfault.

Comment: Thats true. That was just a typo. But do you see any other issue related to using the slopen and dlsym the way that I have tried to explain above that may cause the issue? Why is that the dlsym returned value is different as shown above. Could you point me to some example or any usage where this might have been attempted? I tried looking around and found no such usage

Comment: @OP: Please edit your post and quote the actual code.

Comment: My bet goes on the *real* `myfile.c` missing to include `dlfcn.h`, so the prototype for `dlsym()` is missing and the compiler takes it as defaulting to return `int`.